# Which ImageMagic command can write image metadata?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm talking about this metadata:

[image]

I know that this command:

```
magick mogrify -strip image.jpg
```

can clear all the info. But I don't know is it possible to write some metadata with ImageMagic?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
convert input.png -set new_attribute "attribute value" output.png
```

At least it works according to imagemagick's `identify -verbose`, I can't test if these properties show up on windows too.
It should also be simple to overwrite other metadata, simply by first finding the actual key with `identify -verbose`, I guess.

For more information, here's the official documentation:

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set

Comment: ImageMagick cannot write meta data other than the comment and label fields. The -set command  (other than -set comment or -set label) does not write to the stored meta fields. It only writes to in-memory for use later in the same command line. If you want to write to stored meta fields, then best to use EXIFTOOL or the like.